# Can http_referrer be blank legitimately

Tags: php

I know that files that get called directly have blank http_referrer. Can I assume that in all other cases, there should be an http_referrer?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't assume that.  Many browsers (and browser plugins) allow the REFERER to be switched off. It is not good practice to rely on it at all, except possibly to provide some secondary functionality.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that files that get called directly have blank http_referrer

Nope. It is not blank, there is no referrer at all

> Can I assume that in all other cases, there should be an http_referrer?

No. You should assume that there will be a referrer from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.
Some overcautious software can strip it or substitute with something irrelevant, like `Field is blocked by Outpost`

Comment: And some nieve user agent checking finds `ie` there and treats it as IE :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

- Some browsers allow you to turn it off.
- However you can refuse to serve files to them if you wish.